# Build PIE chart for android app using Achart-engine

Tags: android, sqlite, charts, achartengine

I apologize as I am not android developer even I am working on it!

I am trying to create pie chart from data stored in sqlight. First I tested achartengine demo example. Given here [Achartengine Pie chart](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/PieChartBuilder.java). It shows me fine.

It ask user to insert data and show slice as new data get inserted.

I want data inserted by user to store in sqlite database and on button click show chart.

I dont know what code navigation should I follow. someone please guide.

Comment: I doubt anyone understand what the questions is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following things. If i get u right . you want to show pie chart by the data stored in a sqlite databse that is entered by the user. here are the steps that you can follow.

Inserting values to database by the user. if you know basic stuff this tutorial can help you [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JyC_xv20yE&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=111) in creating a UI to insert values to a sqlite database.

For using these values to create a chart you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862159/need-help-in-integrating-achart-engine-with-database-for-android) .

I hope this helps.